# How do I kick a discord user with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a simple discord bot with node.js but when I try to use a command, nothing happens. Nothing that should get logged gets logged on the console except the discord bot going online.

```js
const Prefix = '$';

bot.on('ready', () => {
 console.log('The Bot Is Logged In');
});

bot.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.author.bot === true) return;
 if (message.content.startsWith === Prefix) {
  const [Cmd_name, ...args] = message.content
   .trim()
   .substring(Prefix.length)
   .split(/\s+/);
  if (Cmd_name === 'kick') {
   if (args.length === 0) return message.reply('Please Provide A User ID');
   const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0]);
   if (member) {
    member.kick();
   } else {
    message.reply('That member was not found');
   }
  }
 }
});
bot.login(process.env.DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN);
```

Can someone explain what went wrong?

Comment: `message.content.startsWith()` is a function, call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) is a function, not a string, and thus you must call it as a function.

```js
if (message.content.startsWith(Prefix)) {
```